# dividing samples in equal slabs

Tags: analysis, statistics, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

[image]

I have sample data like in above format along X, Y axis. Now what i would like to do is to devide  it in "n" number of slabs having fixed values. Now how do i achive this in mathematics(statistics).

Please guide me to good and simple tutorial so that i can understand it. I would like to use this in computer algorithm to solve one problem.

I learned it in school, college and now i am having hard time to remember, understand and interpret it. I wish i could have done it more seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you interested in binning the data? If so, there are a few algorithms that you can use to group the data. But first you need to decide what method to use to bin the data. The most popular methods are "equal width" and "equal frequency".  Sound like you need "equal width". Here are a couple of links.

http://cs-people.bu.edu/dgs/courses/cs105/lectures/data_mining_preparation.pdf
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

-Ralph Winters

Comment: Thanks that really helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your slabs to all (except the first?) have the same thickness.  So slab $i$ would be at $a+di$ where $d$ is the thickness.  In your example, $a=4, d=2$.  I don't see what use you are making of the points, the line, or the curve through the points.

Comment: I would really like to do the slabs based on the concentration of the points.

Comment: Then you need to define how.  Nothing in the figure gives any suggestion that I can see.  Given $a$ and $d$ you can find which slab each point goes into based on its $y$ value by $i=\frac{y-a}{d}$ and taking either the ceiling or floor depending upon whether slab 1 covers $(0,6)$ or $(6,8)$